# SQL function parsing out text from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

i have a table with some text i want to parse out and i'm very close to the solution but its not quite there. i have a column called indicatornumerator and i want to parse out similar to below ie i want to each of the values in between the square brackets onto a new row. as you can see from the output below i am getting a repeat for the first value after the minus. this does not happen for those which do not have a minus.

[image]

my function is as follows:

```
alter function fn_breakdown (@string varchar(max))
returns @breakdown table
(
    originalstr varchar(max),
    breakdownstr varchar(max)
)
as
begin
    while charindex('r',@string,1) >0
    begin
        insert into @breakdown
        select @string,
        SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('r',@string,1),CHARINDEX(']',@string,1)-CHARINDEX('r',@string,1))
        set @string = right(@string,len(@string)-CHARINDEX(')',@string,1))
    end
    return
end
```

a second thing i would like to do is to return those after the minus as a minus value rather eg. -R101 instead of R101 as i need to subtract those values later.

Any help much appreciated

the below should create a temporary table and will show you the output i'm getting. you will see that one of the rows duplicates. i am looking to have one row for each value beginning with 'R' in the indicatornumerator column

create table #temped2
(
indicatornumerator varchar(max)
)

insert into #temped2
select '(SUM([R4]) + SUM([R1010])) - (SUM([R1035]) + SUM([R1034]))'

select * from #temped2
cross apply fn_breakdown(indicatornumerator)

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output.

Comment: Please specify your RDBMS

Comment: the sample output is in the screenshot. on the left is the original string and on the right is desired output. i want the original string to parse onto separate rows but as you can see in the screenshot, some are duplicating. also i'm using SQL server 2017

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Post DML.

Comment: For your first problem try replacing the ')' in the `SET` with ']'. For your second problem you might want to search for parsing of an arithmetic expression and getting the atoms from it. As that's effectively what you're trying to do here. But note, that your parenthesis are unbalanced. I think there's missing a '(' at the beginning of `IndicatorNumerator`.

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of [ngrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) and then:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (IndicatorNumerator varchar(1000));
INSERT @yourtable
SELECT 'SUM([R4]) + SUM([R1010]) - SUM([R50]) + SUM([R200])' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUM([R554]) + SUM([R210]) - SUM([R500]) + SUM([R999])';

-- Solution
SELECT 
  t.IndicatorNumerator,
  breakdownstr = substring(t.IndicatorNumerator, ng.position+1, n.d-ng.position-1)
FROM @yourtable t
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8k(t.IndicatorNumerator, 2) ng
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (charindex(']',t.IndicatorNumerator, ng.position+1))) n(d)
WHERE ng.token = '[R';
```

Returns:

```
IndicatorNumerator                                       breakdownstr
-------------------------------------------------------- --------------
SUM([R4]) + SUM([R1010]) - SUM([R50]) + SUM([R200])      R4
SUM([R4]) + SUM([R1010]) - SUM([R50]) + SUM([R200])      R1010
SUM([R4]) + SUM([R1010]) - SUM([R50]) + SUM([R200])      R50
SUM([R4]) + SUM([R1010]) - SUM([R50]) + SUM([R200])      R200
SUM([R554]) + SUM([R210]) - SUM([R500]) + SUM([R999])    R554
SUM([R554]) + SUM([R210]) - SUM([R500]) + SUM([R999])    R210
SUM([R554]) + SUM([R210]) - SUM([R500]) + SUM([R999])    R500
SUM([R554]) + SUM([R210]) - SUM([R500]) + SUM([R999])    R999
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code if you are using SQL Server 2016 and avove

```
;WITH cte_date
    AS
    (
        SELECT indicatornumerator, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(indicatornumerator,'(',''),')',''),'[',''),']',''),'SUM',''),'- ','-') ParsedData 
        FROM #temped2
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_date
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ParsedData, ' ')
WHERE [VALUE] != '+';
```

Below script will work older than sql server 2016

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrParse]
               (@delimiter CHAR(1),  
                @csv       NTEXT)  
RETURNS @tbl TABLE(Keys  NVARCHAR(255))  
AS  

  BEGIN  
    DECLARE  @len INT  
    SET @len = Datalength(@csv)  
    IF NOT @len > 0  
      RETURN  

    DECLARE  @l INT  
    DECLARE  @m INT  

    SET @l = 0  
    SET @m = 0  

    DECLARE  @s VARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE  @slen INT  

    WHILE @l <= @len  
      BEGIN  

        SET @l = @m + 1--current position  
        SET @m = Charindex(@delimiter,Substring(@csv,@l + 1,255)) 

        IF @m <> 0  
          SET @m = @m + @l  
        --insert @tbl(keys) values(@m)  
        SELECT @slen = CASE   
                         WHEN @m = 0 THEN 255 
                         ELSE @m - @l  
                       END  

        IF @slen > 0  
          BEGIN  
            SET @s = Substring(@csv,@l,@slen)  
            INSERT INTO @tbl  
                       (Keys)  
            SELECT @s  
          END  

        SELECT @l = CASE   
                      WHEN @m = 0 THEN @len + 1  
                      ELSE @m + 1  
                    END 
      END  

    RETURN  
  END

GO

;WITH cte_date
    AS
    (
        SELECT indicatornumerator, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(indicatornumerator,'(',''),')',''),'[',''),']',''),'SUM',''),'- ','-'),'+ ','') ParsedData 
        FROM #temped2
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_date
CROSS APPLY dbo.StrParse(' ', ParsedData)
go
```

Comment: This will only work provided the OP is using SQL 2016+. (A good argument for OPs to include the SQL version they are using when posting)